# How to handle solr replication when master goes down

Tags: solr, lucene, replication, solrj

I have solr setup, which is configured for Master and slave. The indexing is happening in master and slave is replicating the index at every 2 Min interval from master. So there is a delay of 2 Minutes in getting data from master to slave. Lets assume that my master was indexing at 10:42 some data but due to some hardware issue, master went down at 10:43. So now the data which was indexing at 10:42 was suppose to replicate on Slave by 10:44 (as we have set two minutes interval) Since now the master is not available, how to identify what the last indexed data in solr Master server.  Is there way in solr log to track the index activity.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr does log the indexing operations if you have the Solr log set to `INFO`. Any commit/add will show up in the log, so you can check the log for when the last addition was made. Depending on the setup, it might be hard to get the last log when then server is down, though.

You can reduce the time between replications to get more real time replication, or use SolrCloud instead (which should distribute the documents as they're being indexed).

There are also API endpoints (see which connections the Admin interface makes when browsing to the 'replication' status page) for getting the replication status, but those wouldn't help you if the server is gone.

In general - if the server isn't available, you'll have a hard time telling when it was last indexed to. You can work around a few of the issues by storing the indexing time outside of Solr from the indexing task, for example updating a value in memcache or MySQL every time you send something to be indexed from your application.